# SpriteKit applyImpulse and velocity

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to calculate the maximum height of a projectile in SpriteKit.

My problem is that I cannot come up with a working formula. According to the documentation. The applyImpulse method should change the sprite's velocity instantly. As far as I know, the impulse = mass * initial velocity. However, when I apply an impulse with a CGVector like (0,10) the measured velocity is far from my calculations.

Thank you!